# Vue.js: Play CSS animation on JavaScript event

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

In my Vue.js app, I have a login form, which I want to shake whenever login attempt fails.

I achieved the desired effect, but I'm not happy with my solution. Here's my simplified code:

```js
const Home = {
    data() {
        return {
            shakeForm: false
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <form :class="{'form-shaking': shakeForm}"
                  @submit.prevent="login"
                  @animationend="shakeForm = false;"
            >
                form fields
            </form>
        </div>
    `,
    methods: {
        async login() {
            // ...
            const rawResponse = await fetchLogin();

            if (!rawResponse.ok) {
                this.shakeForm = true;
                return;
            }

            // login ok
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.form-shaking {
    position: relative;
    animation: shake-horizontally .2s ease-out 2;
}

@keyframes shake-horizontally {
    from {
        left: 0;
    }

    25% {
        left: 25px;
    }

    75% {
        left: -25px;
    }

    to {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

So basically, I'm playing with the `shakeForm` boolean property, which adds the `form-shaking` class to the `<form>`. Then I remove the class on `@animationend` event (to be able to play it again).

Is there a dedicated Vue.js feature to handle scenarios like this? I looked up the transition/animation features, but couldn't find anything suitable.

Comment: I really don't see any technical downside to your current solution. It's reliable, performant, does exactly what it's supposed to, cross-browser, cross-device. Which is basically the definition of quality code. What do you mean by *fancy*? Regardless, the question is off-topic here, for at least three reasons: **a)** it's a code review question, so it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ; **b)** we have no way of knowing what makes you happy (and happiness is volatile). **c)** it's opinion based (lacks criteria definition for quantifying answers).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (if it would include technical requirements from solution currently not met by presented solution).

Comment: Well, it's not the first time I'm asking a question of this kind. By "better solution" I mean some dedicated framework feature. Vue.js has quite a few transition and animation features, but I couldn't find anything to handle simple event-driven scenario. My solution uses the basic Vue.js patterns to achieve that effect, but is kinda tricky. I hope you get the idea what I'm trying to do here. I'm not looking for a "working" solution (mine works), but to find a framework feature that is meant to do what I did.

Comment: @tao [Don't use the existence of Code Review as a reason to close a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400). From now on evaluate the question and use a reason like; needs focus, primarily opinion-based, etc. This question is likely to be off-topic on Code Review for missing context - "Here's my simplified code". Please familiarize yourself with what is [on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @tao I understand your thinking pattern, but I kindly disagree. That's not a code review request, because it's very basic Vue.js stuff to explain what I need.

Comment: In that case, my suggestion is to reformulate the question and specify in clear what you're looking for. And what I mean is that your comment makes a lot more sense than the whole question. At least we now know it's not about your feelings. Ref the issue at hand, the dedicated framework features are precisely wrappers around methods like yours. What you have here is quality code. You shouldn't dismiss it because it's too explicit. Code transparency is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Peilonrayz, that's why I specified in my close vote it should be reformulated for code review as it would likely be off-topic there as well, in current form. The problem the question has in current form is it doesn't define the requirements for a qualified answer.

Comment: @tao I often ask questions on Stack Overflow to educate myself on the best patterns. Not the opinionated best, but the most focused features. But some of these questions get criticized and the others get upvotes. That's a bit confusing. I hope it's more clear now why I'm asking these things.

Comment: @tao yet the reason was "_because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com_" which is **using the existence of CR as a reason to close a question**... ["The fact that a question is on topic on some site does not make it off topic on every other site. There is some amount of overlap between sites. Given that, the close reason you've given is always going to be an invalid reason for closing a question."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287401/1575353)

Comment: Well, I can't speak for others, but for me the question was confusing at the time I read it. I only understood what you wanted after you commented in response to my initial comment. The answers were also indicating their authors didn't understand what you're after, as you already noticed. On topic, the only "dedicated" feature Vue has is the ability to define any method for your animation using your code or some third-party library and trigger it whenever you want: [Dynamic State Transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Dynamic-State-Transitions).

Comment: @Sam, in the previous comment to the closing one, I gave 3 reasons for it being off-topic. Because I had already written them down, I only specified one of them in the close vote comment.

Comment: I have seen these dynamic state transitions and at first I thought that's what I need. But they seem to be something completely different, they do transition the state value itself, like the range. Am I wrong?

Comment: @tao and on a serious note, I think that's the neurotic part of me that looks for the best (not opinion-based best, but - again - most focused) solution to problems. I have actually found quite a few great features by asking questions like this here. But some of my other questions of the same kind have been closed.

Comment: @Robo, no, you're not wrong. They allow complete control over the transition. Speed, transition function, direction, play-pause, etc... And they're aimed at much "fancier" (s.i.c.) use cases. Ref your question, my intention was to help clarify what you wanted, which you did. That's exactly the role comments should have. I don't know how I could have done it better.

Comment: You could cancel your Close vote (which I think you did) :P Thanks for asking for clarification, I also edited the last part of my question to explain why I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could always manually edit the `styles.animation` attribute of the form on the fly, to make it shake, like so:

```
function shake() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('form-shaking')[0].style.animation = 'shake-horizontally .2s ease-out 2';
    // stop the animation after the animation ends
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('form-shaking')[0].style.animation = 'unset';
    }, 400);
}
```

(In order for the function to work, the animation must be unset at the time of function call.)

As an example, you could use the following as a demo (driver code):

```js
function shake() {
    console.log('Incorrect Login: shaking form...')
    document.getElementsByClassName('form-shaking')[0].style.animation = 'shake-horizontally .2s ease-out 2';
    // stop the animation after the animation ends
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('form-shaking')[0].style.animation = 'unset';
        console.log('Incorrect Login: form shake state reset.')
    }, 400);
}

window.setTimeout(shake, 1000)
window.setTimeout(shake, 2000)
window.setTimeout(shake, 3000)
```

```css
.form-shaking {
    position: relative;
    /* animation: shake-horizontally .2s ease-out 2; */
}

@keyframes shake-horizontally {
    from {
        left: 0;
    }

    25% {
        left: 25px;
    }

    75% {
        left: -25px;
    }

    to {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CSS Animation on JS Event</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-shaking" style="margin: 32px; display: inline-block; background-color: black; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm looking for the more fancy solution over my own one. I don't see how does your improve anything, quite the contrary actually.